# Why doesn't my Django WMD MarkDownField install work?

Tags: django, wmd-editor

I'm trying to use [django-wmd-editor](http://github.com/scrum8/django-wmd-editor)... And failing hard. I'm trying to use it as an admin field. Here's the relevant bit of my Model:

```
from wmd import models as wmd_models

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    content = wmd_models.MarkDownField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The media is symlinked into the right place and can be requested.

Now, if you believe the README, this should be enough for an admin form... But looking in firebug, none of the media is being asked for, let alone hitting a 404.

Is there some sort of secret handshake I need to perform to get this to work?

Comment: is `wmd` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yeah. Config table synced in too.